# What is the fastest algorithm for this assignment?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a 2x2 grid and I have 5 tokens. I want to place 4 of the 5 tokens on the grid.

Each token has a different value depending on where they are placed on the grid. Essentially if they should not be placed in a certain position they are awarded a value of 20, otherwise they have a score lower than 20.

I am writing a program that needs to figure out which 4 tokens should be placed, in order to use the ones with the lowest value possible.

I need this part of the program to be as fast as possible. I'm wondering if there is an optimal algorithm I should use. In my research I have come across the Hungarian algorithm, but I'm wondering if there is another option I should be considering.

Here is an example of the problem:

My grid has its' positions labelled, a,b,c,d ...

`+--------+--------+
|   c    |   d    |
|        |        |
+--------+--------+
|   a    |   b    |
|        |        |
+--------+--------+`

And I have the following tokens with corresponding values for each location on the grid...

`a   b   c   d
token_p = [20, 20, 15, 20]
token_r = [ 1,  1, 20, 20]
token_s = [15, 20, 20, 20]
token_t = [20, 10, 20, 10]
token_u = [20, 20,  5, 20]`

The answer should be:

token_s at position a (value 15)
token_r at position b (value 1)
token_u at position c (value 5)
token_t at position d (value 10)

**UPDATE**
This is the simplest scenario for the problem. I hadn't considered that it was simple enough that an algorithm would not be required. The 'hardest' scenario would be to have a 5x5 grid with, 30 tokens to choose from.

Comment: I expect that it would be possible to try all 120 possibilities with word-parallelism faster than it would be to execute the Hungarian algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you are putting five different objects (tokens) into five different places (four grid positions, and one left out). Each of the 5! = 120 permutations can be the optimal answer. So, one solution would be to check all the permutations: 120 is not that much. Some straightforward implementation like the following would be a start:

```
sum = 0
for p0 in 0..4:
    sum += a[0][p0]
    for p1 in 0..4 if p1!=p0:
        sum += a[1][p1]
        ... and three more nested loops
            best = min (best, sum)
        sum -= a[1][p1]
    sum -= a[0][p0]
```

Here, `a` is a 5x5 array containing the costs, much like your five token arrays (the cost of dropping each token is zero).

If you come to a theoretically faster solution, I'd suggest to benchmark against a baseline solution above. For instance, the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) is O(n^3), and with n=5, it is unclear whether it will speed up things.

Comment: If I had 30 tokens to place on a 5x5 grid, do you think I'd still be better going through all the permutations?

Comment: @PaulSturgess: Not exactly permutations, but there would be 30! / 5! ~ 2 * 10^30 ways to do that - right, that's too much.

Comment: OK I've updated the question as originally I only asked about solving the simplest scenario. I hadn't considered that it was simple enough that an algorithm would not be required. The 'hardest' scenario would be to have a 5x5 grid with, 30 tokens to choose from.